# How to add @timestamp field to Audit.Net event before sending into ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, audit.net

I am using [Audit.Net](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) with [ElasticSearch DataProvider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET.ElasticSearch/README.md) to store API logs into an Elastic index.

And I need to implement Elastic search ILM on that index, but to do this a "@timestamp" field need to be set in the root of the document that elastic index receives.

So how can I edit the Event data to add this "@timestamp" field before sending data from my application api logs to ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't tested this, but you could try setting a [Custom Field](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-fields-and-comments) on a [Custom Action](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-actions), for example:

```cs
Audit.Core.Configuration.AddCustomAction(ActionType.OnScopeCreated, scope =>
{
    scope.SetCustomField("@timestamp", DateTime.UtcNow);
});
```

That should be serialized as a field on the root object.